# C# precompiler directive to avoid reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, compatibility, preprocessor-directive

In my scenario i have some version of the same library.

For example suppose that my library name is lib.dll and there are two version of that library.

In this example each library contain only one class ( called Dummy ) with only one method, but the method's signature change in each library depending on the version.

Now i need to develop a new library that use the previous lib.dll but need to be compatible with each version.

Suppose that lib.dll with versione 1.0.0.0 support that method :

```
Dummy.Method ( int )
```

lib.dll with version 2.0.0.0 instead suppot that method :

```
Dummy.Method ( string , int )
```

In the library that i am developing using lib.dll i would be able to be retrocompatible with both lib.dll versions but without use reflection to call the method with different signature.
Is there any support to precompiler syntax like that :

```
 #IF lib.dll VERSION IS 1.0.0.0 
      Dummy.Method ( 1 ) ;
 #ENDIF

 #IF lib.dll VERSION IS 2.0.0.0 
      Dummy.Method ( "test" , 1 ) ;
 #ENDIF
```

so that according to the referenced version of the library; one branch of code, or the other is used.

Comment: Do you want your compiled assembly to only be compatible with one of the old libraries, not both?

Comment: And no, there are no compiler directives that can handle this problem that way. You could add a define name in the project build options, and use `#if lib_1` and `#if lib_2` but it wouldn't be automatic depending on which assembly version you've referenced.

Comment: If you want early binding like your example shows (as opposed to Reflection or `dynamic`), then you're already going to have to make two builds of your new library -- one that references lib_1 and one that references lib_2. At that point, it shouldn't be a problem to specify different conditional compilation directives (as Lasse suggested) based on which version you're compiling against.

Comment: @JoeWhite is not clear to me how can i specify a directive compilation in your scenario, i suppose i need not only to change the lib.dll on wich i would be compatible to but some #definition directive that tell to me which lib.dll version is the currently used or i miss the point ?
Thanks again for help

Comment: Project properties > Build tab > Conditional compilation symbols. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(cs.ProjectPropertiesBuild);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z(v=vs.140).aspx). Build once with one conditional compilation symbol (e.g. `lib_1`) and again with another. It's a fair bit of work, but it's also a very unusual requirement you're trying to satisfy.

Comment: This seems very [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Has the v2 of the dependency actually _removed_ the v1 method? If so, that seems like a major issue right there. If not, then your library should just constrain itself to the available API in v1. Alternatively, it's not clear what the reason for avoiding reflection is here; done properly, it should not incur a significant overhead on the program. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @PeterDuniho 6 year ago, the company in which i work has some requirements for plugin's code. Avoid reflection is one of them. For XY Problem you may be right, but if i remeber right, at the time the library i talking about was developed by another "branch" of the same company.. so may be a mistake that the method change that way, but i had little or no control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# under Visual Studio 2019 does have a facility to achieve this.

They are called generators.

(see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/).

The idea is to create your method during compile time.
The generator would thus check the version of the lib.dll version and generate adequate code for calling the actual method - Dummy.method() above.

Comment: @Wolfang seems an interesting technology, i'll keep in mind. Meanwhile situation changed a lot and i have not that problem anymore. Anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Skary: _"i have not that problem anymore"_ -- if the problem no longer exists and you don't a way to properly evaluate an answer to this question, especially to determine whether an answer should be accepted or not, then it's best if you just delete the question so as to not distract from questions that can be answered and accepted.

Comment: @PeterDuniho so questions that remain opened for years should be deleted in the moment on which can no longer be evaluated? Pretty hard task to deal with, hope an auto-delete (based on timeout over open questions) will be put in place by stackoverflow; meanwhile thanks for the hint i'll keep in mind. PS : i doen't delete this question yet because meantime i have forwarded it to my previous colleagues.